# can we use same Adapter for populating diffrent listviews having same type of elements eg(Textview,ImageViews)

Tags: android

This might sound a bit funny but i want to know if we can use the same Adapter and implement **constructor overloading** on adapter class

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible, you can create a new instance of your listAdapter.
You should have in your constructor a parameter of your activity or your context